# How can I get font awesome icons to show up on the pages for account management in Asp.Net Core Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, font-awesome, asp.net-core-identity

In my app's main `_Layout.cshtml`, I am linking to the Font Awesome stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/fontawesome/css/all.css" />
```

... and icons are appearing where I expect them to. Except for the razor pages concerning account management under Identity.

The `_Layout.cshtml`-file for account management sits in `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage`. It does not contain `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>`-tags, so there's no place there to add a `<link rel...`. I am however able to get icons working if I add those tags in, but that results in a nested set of tags, and is a hacky workaround.

Icons **are** displayed in these files (among others):

```
Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml
Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml
```

But **not** in these (among others):

```
Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/Index.cshtml
Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage/Email.cshtml
```

How can I get it working for the files inside `../Manage/` without "hacking"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `_Layout.cshtml`-file for account management sits in `/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Manage`.
>
> It does not contain ,  or -tags, so there's no place there to add a `<link rel....`

To add reference to fontawesome css file(s), you can directly link to style sheet file of fontawesome icons in `Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml` page, like below.

```
@{
    Layout = "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<link href="~/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h1>Manage your account</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Change your account settings</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <partial name="_ManageNav" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```

Besides, if you also specify `/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml` as the layout page of `Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml` as above, adding reference to `~/fontawesome/css/all.css` in  section of `/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml` page would works too.

Test Result

[image]